# Has there been any foreshadowing of Captain Marvel in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, reference

The [Wikipedia article on the Marvel Cinematic Universe feature films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe#Feature_films) says that in 2019 a new hero will be introduced to the MCU - **Captain Marvel**.

Has there been any foreshadowing for this character in the MCU so far? Some hints or references only the comic readers would understand?

Something similar to the reference to Doctor Strange in *Winter Soldier*, where "Stephen Strange" was on Hydra's list alongside Bruce Banner? Or that Spider-Man reference in Ant-Man?

> Well, we got everything nowadays. We got a guy who jumps, we got a guy who swings, we got a guy who crawls up the walls [...]

Comment: I don't see the point of having "Captain Marvel" as a spoiler when it's in the question title. I don't think it's a spoiler anyway.

Comment: In light of what we now know about the Captain Marvel movie and setting, [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160426/has-there-been-any-foreshadowing-of-captain-marvel-in-the-mcu#comment520371_160427) seems right, so you should probably unaccept the current answer.

Comment: ... [and this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/191760/3823), while short, is probably correct.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Before *Infinity War* was released, and *Captain Marvel*'s setting details were announced, the "foreshadowing" was as follows.**

As I mentioned in [another answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/153966/70236), one of the patients alluded to in *Doctor Strange*, when Stephen is in his car right before the crash *could* be Captain Marvel - the "22-year old female with an electronic implant in her brain that controls schizophrenia - struck by lightning".

Fans have identified this being somehow similar to Captain Marvel's backstory, and some magazines have asked the director whether it's true, to which they've got the following responses (emphasis mine):

> There’s been some speculation that this could be Carol Danvers, aka Brie Larson’s Captain Marvel, which is currently in pre-production. Derrickson is coy about it, but doesn’t deny the rumour, either. **“All I can is...maybe. That one, you're going to have to wait and see...”**
>    <sub>[Empire Online](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/doctor-strange-scott-derrickson/)</sub>

And for Entertainment Weekly:

> Another patient mention in Strange’s call is much more likely to be an important Marvel character in the future. Strange was far more interested in working on her: a woman in her 20s who was struck by lightning – a serious injury complicated by an electronic implant in her brain to help quell her schizophrenia.
>
> When asked if this was a reference to Captain Marvel, who will be played by Oscar-winner Brie Larson in an upcoming film, **Derrickson said he could neither confirm nor deny. But he was smiling (so infer from that what you like).**
>
> “Remember that Brittany Murphy movie where she goes ‘I’ll never tell…’” he said in a whispered singsong, referencing the 2001 thriller Don’t Say a Word.
>    <sub>[Entertainment Weekly](http://ew.com/article/2016/11/05/doctor-strange-easter-eggs-spoilers/)</sub>

Comment: “Remember that Brittany Murphy movie where she goes ‘I’ll never tell…’”” — no-one does.

Comment: It's unlikely that that's her, since we know now that Captain Marvel will be set in the 90s.

Comment: The problem is the timeline as we now know definitively Captain Marvel is set in the 90s. Hard for her to be a 20 something pilot in Dr Stange that way.

Answer (score 14):

The only foreshadowing of Captain Marvel thus far has been her symbol appearing on Nick Fury's phone/pager/thingie during the credits stinger of *Infinity War*.